# When and when not to use webservices?

Tags: java, performance, web-services

we are creating an appraisal system ,in which there will be a no. of validations and computations. Team leader decided to use web services for most of their logic ,which we are going to write. 
  I am just curious ,when we can moreover when we should web services and  when we should avoid using it?

Comment: This would be an interesting question if you provided more details. Do it so it gets reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The team leader decided to use web services for most of their logic.

I would not advise putting the logic in web service code. Put it in a business logic layer, that can then be exposed via, for example, web services.

> When should web services not be used?

When they are unncessary - without a specific scenario it's difficult to give a more meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using web services for method invocations that can be resolved locally (on the same JVM). Otherwise, use them.

Answer (score 0):

Web services are the best/easiest way to do distributed operations. For example central server and many clients. If you have that sort of architecture then you need either web services or a web application.

If everything is stand-alone and local though then you don't need them and they will be less efficient than just doing things directly.

Answer (score 0):

Web services and web application..

web services provide a standard means of interoperating between software applications.

When all major platforms could access the Web using Web browsers, different platforms couldn't interact. For these platforms to work together, Web-applications were developed.